# Show that $O(\text{max}\{f(n),g(n)\})=O(f(n)+g(n))$

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

Show that $O(\text{max}\{f(n),g(n)\})=O(f(n)+g(n))$

Can I keep the same constant $c$ in each of the cases?

Consider two cases:
$$1)f(n)>g(n);O(\text{max}\{f(n),g(n)\})⇒O(f(n))\Rightarrow d(n) ≤c⋅f(n);c>0$$
$$2)f(n)≤g(n);O(\text{max}\{f(n),g(n)\})⇒O(g(n))\Rightarrow e(n)≤c⋅g(n);c>0$$
Combining the 2 cases yields:
$$d(n)+e(n)≤c⋅f(n)+c⋅g(n)$$
$$d(n)+e(n)≤c⋅(f(n)+g(n))$$
Which is definition of $O(f(n)+g(n))$

Comment: Lucky for you, $O$ does not imply _a (single)_ constant. Check the definition!

Comment: Everything is fine except for the same constant part. Assume $c_1$ and $c_2$ and then while combining assume another constant $c$ with $c>c_1$ and $c  >c_2$ using this assumption... Get an inequality from the inequations 1 and 2 and then while adding the inequalities as you did, replace $c_1$ and $c_2$ by $c$ and from your assumption you have ur answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the proof is fine except for the fact that you have used same costant in two different eqns. Even if you use(and you must use, because the constant you choose is arbitrary) two different conts say c1 and c2, the solution will imply the same.